# Can I get picture from Umbraco with GetCropUrl?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6

I have uploaded an image to my Umbraco and I have not made crop images.

It is just a normal photo upload.

But is it possible that I can use `GetCropUrl` with some parameters to retrieve this image ?.
Or do I have to do so

```
@if (Model.Content.HasValue("caseStudyImage"))
{
    var caseStudyImage = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("caseStudyImages");
    var caseStudyImage = Umbraco.TypedMedia(caseStudyImagesList);

    <img src="@caseStudyImage.Url" style="width:300px;height:300px" />      

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Umbraco uses [ImageProcessor](http://imageprocessor.org/) so you can resize images by adding the appropriate query string parameters to the image URL.  So in your case you could do the following:

```
<img src="@caseStudyImage.Url?width=300&height=300" />
```

You could also use the `GetCropUrl` method by passing in the image dimensions:

```
<img src="@caseStudyImage.GetCropUrl(propertyAlias: "umbracoFile", height: 300, width: 300)" />
```

See the [Umbraco docs](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/image-cropper) for more information.